# get random value but not twice the same one

Tags: c++, qt, random

Questions are stored like:

```
 arr[y][x] = { "Question1text" , "answer1" , "answer2" , "answer3" , .... , "boolean" }
```

get random Question

```
randomQuestion = qrand() % questionCount;
```

I set nr 6 to = "1" when i already used that question, so i now look
for a random one but without "1" set

```
while( question[randomQuestion][6] == "1" )
{
    randomQuestion = qrand() % questionCount;
}
```

but let's say there's just 1 question out of 10k left. the chance of the random number to hit exactly that question ain't so bright.
So there's gotta be a better way of achieving this, but how?

Comment: Just pick the next unused one, well, if true randomness in statistics is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_Shuffle) the questions, then simply iterate through the shuffled set.  When you get to the end of the set, re-shuffle and start over. Shuffling `n` questions takes `O(n)` work, so as long as you're storing them in memory anyway this is a cheap and simple solution.

Comment: brilliant gonna be a lil work to do that for a 2D array but it will be fast

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using an old-school array you could store your questions (define a class or struct for a single question) in a list-class like QList.
Then you can remove the questions after they are used...

try something like this:

```
randomQuestion = qrand() % questionList.count();
nextQuestion = questionList.takeAt(randomQuestion);
```

Comment: You're right normally I'd use a struct. However this is about learning different ways to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard class `std::bitset` that to mark questions that were already selected. Here is an example that you may use as a base

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main() 
{

    const size_t N = 10;
    char s[N][3] = { "Q0", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5", "Q6", "Q7", "Q8", "Q9" };
    std::bitset<N> b;

    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

    size_t availableQuestions = N;

    while ( availableQuestions )
    {
            size_t i = std::rand() % availableQuestions;
            size_t question = 0;
            while ( i != 0 || b[question] )
            {
                if ( !b[question++] && i != 0 ) --i;
            }

            b.set( question );
            std::cout << s[question] << std::endl;
            --availableQuestions;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output at the first run is

```
Q1
Q9
Q8
Q4
Q6
Q5
Q3
Q2
Q7
Q0
```

The output at the second run is

```
Q7
Q5
Q0
Q1
Q2
Q4
Q9
Q8
Q6
Q3
```

It would be even better to use a for loop instead of the while loop

```
for ( size_t availableQuestions = N; availableQuestions != 0; --availableQuestions )
{
    size_t i = std::rand() % availableQuestions;
    size_t question = 0;

    while ( i != 0 || b[question] )
    {
        if ( !b[question++] && i != 0 ) --i;
    }

    b.set( question );
    std::cout << s[question] << std::endl;
}
```

Enjoy!:)

Comment: I like the idea, now I just need to figure out if there's a BitSet class implemented in Qt :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```
question[randomQuestion] = question[--questionCount];
```

Answer (score 0):

do not use an array , use list instead so you can remove selected questions from it. then simply select a member of list randomly.